# How to use DATEADD function with variables?

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

In classic ASP, I am unable to use DateAdd() with variables. I see no reason why this should work.

```
strTargetDate=DateAdd("d",visitDate,followDate)
```

visitDate is an incremental value -- 30, 60, 90, 180 etc. followDate is an actual date. However, I receive a type mismatch error using this code. Shouldn't this work??

Comment: @KenWhite VBScript is weakly typed (types are determined by assigned values) and does not obey type prefixes. Except for fixed arrays assignment *never* cause type errors.

Comment: When you say "unable", do you mean you are getting an error or an unexpected result? Edit your question to include the relevant information for either/both options.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner: Who said anything about 'type prefixes'? Variable names are a convenience to the programmer; I'm not aware of any language that actually uses type prefixes ("Hungarian notation") to determine variable types.

Comment: AtEveryBodyExceptKenWhite - don't try to make sense of KenWhite's and my comments (or my reference to his speculations in my answer), because he choose to delete his contributions I was refering to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either visitDate isn't/can't be converted to a number, or followDate isn't/can't be converted to a date. So check the TypeName() of your input and pay attention to date formats.

Partly to show facts against @Ken's speculations:

```
>> s = "string"
>> WScript.Echo 0, s, TypeName(s)
>> s = DateAdd("d", 1, Now)
>> WScript.Echo 1, s, TypeName(s)
>> s = DateAdd("d", "1", CStr(now))
>> WScript.Echo 2, s, TypeName(s)
>> s = DateAdd("d", 1, "20/10/2013")
>>
0 string String
1 24.10.2013 17:05:54 Date
2 24.10.2013 17:05:54 Date
>> s = DateAdd("d", 1, "32.13.1")
>>
Error Number:       13
Error Description:  Type mismatch
```

**Update wrt comment:**

As computations involving Null should propagate Null, this

```
>> WScript.Echo TypeName(DateAdd("d", 1, Null))
>>
Null
>>
```

is no surprise. While you should handle Nulls for your DateAdd() in a way appropriate to your application, they are not the cause for the type mismatch.

Empty strings (""), however, could well be the culprits:

```
>> WScript.Echo TypeName(DateAdd("d", 1, ""))
>>
Error Number:       13
Error Description:  Type mismatch
>>
```

Comment: Im receiving a type mismatch on followDate. Would null DB entries in the table cause that?

Comment: @SteveWeaver Please follow the advice you were given: check the [`TypeName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y58s1cs6%28v=vs.84%29) of your two input values.

Comment: Both return as a string type. I just checked both. Will DateAdd not accept two string inputs? Also both variables return values. followDate returns the number 60, visitDate is returning a valid date.

Comment: @SteveWeaver Then your arguments are in the wrong order. Since you're calling `DateAdd("d", visitDate, followDate)`, `visitDate` should have the value `60`, and `followDate` should have the date string.

Comment: Man I really hope thats not what I did. Ill check again as soon as I get to work in the morning and let you know.

Comment: Thats exactly what the problem was guys. Guess I had just been staring at it so long I didnt realize. I appreciate your help and very sorry to have wasted your time. It is working now.